# Building an Executable JAR Jetty Gradle

Tags: gradle, jetty, executable-jar, embedded-jetty

I’m trying to get a Gradle script to build an executable JAR file that allows execute an embedded Jetty Servlet container via a main class.

Has anyone came across or a reference project that does the above and manages a deployable war (without jetty dependencies) along with an executable JAR file (with jetty dependencies)?

I know its trivial with the jetty plugin however It seems to be a big task with Gradle and no matter how many ways I use Google I can’t find any reference to people talking about this usecase;

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you are finding difficult? What have you tried, and what didn't work? I can probably help you, but I don't have time to put an entire reference proj together :)

Comment: Don't know of any projects per'se that can be referenced but have a look at Spring Boot - those guys seem to be doing it and search for 'shadow plugin gradle' that builds fatjar files..

Answer (score 1):

I made a commit to Johannes Brodwalls excellent example a short while ago. You can take a look at it here: https://github.com/jhannes/java-ee-turnkey

Summarized you can do something along the lines of:

```
task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn:[classes]) {
    main = 'com.MyMainClass'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Challenges that I've not managed to figure out yet is reusing the mainclass in integrationtests. There just does not seem to be a smart way to run a task as a background process.